# Convert if and foreach statement to select and where in linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

How would I go about changing my **if statement** and **foreach** to something cleaner in linq using **select** and **where**.

I've tried to make the if statement into a **where** clause and then use the **select** query as a replacement for the **Foreach** loop but that seem to have type issues and wasn't working.

```
{
                StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _appSettings.StripeSecretKey;

                var profile = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(customerServiceID);
                var stripeId = profile.StripeAccountId;
                if (stripeId == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("No associated Stripe account found.");

                List<PaymentMethodDto> result = new List<PaymentMethodDto>();

                var options = new PaymentMethodListOptions
                {
                    Customer = stripeId,
                    Type = "card",
                };

                var service = new PaymentMethodService();

                var payments = await service.ListAsync(options);

                if (payments != null && payments.Data?.Count > 0)
                {
                    payments.Data.ForEach((x) =>
                    {
                        result.Add(
                            new PaymentMethodDto
                            {
                                Brand = x.Card.Brand,
                                LastDigits = x.Card.Last4,
                                StripeToken = x.Id,
                                CustomerID = x.CustomerId
                            });
                    });
                }
                return result;
            }
```

Comment: When would `payments` ever be `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a regular `Select`.

```
List<PaymentMethodDto> result = payments.Data.Select(x => new PaymentMethodDto
                            {
                                Brand = x.Card.Brand,
                                LastDigits = x.Card.Last4,
                                StripeToken = x.Id,
                                CustomerID = x.CustomerId
                            })
                            .ToList();
```

If `payments.Data` has nothing in it, this will give you an empty list, which is what you want.

If `payments` is `null`, you'll get an exception, which I think if you think about it really hard is probably what you really want in that case too. Why would `.ListAsync()` yield a null value?